# Bitmap could not be found

Tags: c#, xaml

Im creating graphic interface using XAML and I have problem with Bitmap type. Using System.Drawing is surprisingly unsused despite created Bitmap objects.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace Cryptography
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Logika interakcji dla klasy MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private int NextStepCounter { get; set; }
        private Bitmap LoadedBitmap { get; set; }
        private Bitmap FirstShareBitmap { get; set; }
        private Bitmap SecondShareBitmap { get; set; }
        private Bitmap ThirdShareBitmap { get; set; }
        private Bitmap FourthShareBitmap { get; set; }
        private Bitmap LoadedFirstShareBitmap { get; set; }
        private Bitmap LoadedSecondShareBitmap { get; set; }
        private Bitmap LoadedThirdShareBitmap { get; set; }
        private Bitmap LoadedFourthShareBitmap { get; set; }
        private Bitmap OverlaidSharesBitmap { get; set; }
```

[image]

Comment: what happens when you compile/build your code?

Comment: CS0246  C# The type or namespace name 'Bitmap' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to install `System.Drawing.Common` from Nuget Package.